# Python telnetlib client doesn't appear to be opening telnet connection to server

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, telnet, telnetlib

I am trying to open a telnet connection, write one string, then print everything from the telnet server in Python. I assume I am missing something obvious because the documentation seems pretty self-explanatory and doing what I think is the exact same thing in terminal works fine.

Here is the Python code:

```
import telnetlib

telnet = telnetlib.Telnet()
telnet.open('192.168.1.128', 9801, 10)
telnet.write("SYSTEM_CAL")

print(telnet.read_all())
```

This times out after 10 seconds / doesn't successfully connect to the server I assume. Here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Work/Scripting/Telnet Test/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(telnet.read_all())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 385, in read_all
    self.fill_rawq()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 576, in fill_rawq
    buf = self.sock.recv(50)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

In the image below I connect to the same server in terminal and everything works fine. At the end I give the "DISCONNECT" command taken by the server which is why the connection closes.

[image: Connecting to Telnet server in terminal]

Am I missing something? Why is this working in Terminal and not in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are sending your command too early, and the receiving end is ignoring it. Try to read the banner first:

```
print(telnet.read_until("Welcome."))
telnet.write("SYSTEM_CAL")
print(telnet.read_all())
```

EDIT:

I also note that you don't have a line-terminating sequence at the end of "SYSTEM_CAL". I presume that, in the interactive session, you press <kbd>↵ ENTER</kbd> after you type "SYSTEM_CAL". If that is the case, you'll need to add `\n` at the end of the `write()` call:

```
telnet.write("SYSTEM_CAL\n")
```

Depending upon other factors outside of your question, it is possible that you may need one of the following instead:

```
telnet.write("SYSTEM_CAL\r")
telnet.write("SYSTEM_CAL\r\n")
```

Comment: I am getting the welcome message when I do this but then it times out. I don't get the COMMAND: OK that should result from from writing SYSTEM_CAL

Comment: @createer - I wonder if your telnet server requires a line terminator in order to process a command. See my recent edit.